# preg_match expression to put a line break between individual HTML tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a HTML file where multiple HTML tags appear on a single line. For example:

`<body class=" yui3-skin-sam controls-visible guest-site signed-out public-page site"> <a href="#main-content" id="skip-to-content">Skip to Content</a> <div id="outer-wrapper"> <div id="wrapper" class="echa-styled live container-fluid"> <div id="content-wrapper"> <a href="#main-content" id="skip-to-content">Skip to Content</a> <header id="banner" role="banner">`

I have a PHP application which reads from this file, and will write it (after some processing to remove various tags) to another file. However, on the output file, I also want to create new lines `"\n"` between each HTML tag. On the example above the desired output is this - the only difference is that the opening of each tag starts on a new line in the output file:

```
<body class=" yui3-skin-sam controls-visible guest-site signed-out public-page site"> 
<a href="#main-content" id="skip-to-content">Skip to Content</a>
<div id="outer-wrapper">
<div id="wrapper" class="echa-styled live container-fluid">
<div id="content-wrapper">
<a href="#main-content" id="skip-to-content">Skip to Content</a>
<header id="banner" role="banner">
```

I have a regular expression which I've already used to strip out some conditional tags which is `preg_replace('/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/', '', $body);`

I was considering modifying this so that instead of targeting the conditional tag (`<!-- -->`), it targets `<` and `>`. I was then going to use it in conjunction with `preg_match`

However I'm not sure how to construct the appropriate `preg_match` condition, particularly in terms of how/where to add the new line character. I guess the first parameter would be `'/<(.|\s)*?>/'` to target any opening/closing HTML tags.

Please can someone advise how to do this or if there is an alternative solution to this problem?

Comment: i have found same solution

Comment: `str_replace('> <' , '>\n<' , $html)` , assuming the tags have a space in between, as in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`(<([^> ]+)[^>]*>)(?![^<>]*<\/\2>)`](https://regex101.com/r/JQNOmV/1)

Replace with `$1\n`.

`<tag properties="values"></tag>` => `<tag properties="values"></tag>`

`<tag properties="values">content</tag>` => `<tag properties="values">content</tag>`

`<tag properties="values"><nested-tag>content</nested-tag></tag>` => `<tag properties="values">\n<nested-tag>content</nested-tag\n</tag>`

Comment: Thanks. Can you edit this or comment on how to construct the `preg_replace` PHP function to use this? Assume the markup (on 1 line, from the input file) is in a var called `$body`

Comment: I don't know PHP. Presumably you just slot the code into the function as you have done: `preg_replace('/(<([^> ]+)[^>]*>)(?![^<>]*<\/\2>)/', "$1\n", $body);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this post has been downvoted as it's a perfectly legitimate programming question.

Anyway, I've found my own solution which was to use this:

`$body = preg_replace('/>/', ">\n", $body);`

No idea if that's right, but I'm accepting it as the answer because nobody else has helped and it does what I want.

Comment: That won't allow `<tag>text</tag>` to stay on the same line. Solution incoming...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$body = '<body class=" yui3-skin-sam controls-visible guest-site signed-out public-page site"> <a href="#main-content" id="skip-to-content">Skip to Content</a> <div id="outer-wrapper"> <div id="wrapper" class="echa-styled live container-fluid"> <div id="content-wrapper"> <a href="#main-content" id="skip-to-content">Skip to Content</a> <header id="banner" role="banner">';

$body = preg_replace("/>/", "> \n", trim($body));

echo $body;

/* output

<body class=" yui3-skin-sam controls-visible guest-site signed-out public-page site"> 
 <a href="#main-content" id="skip-to-content"> 
Skip to Content</a> 
 <div id="outer-wrapper"> 
 <div id="wrapper" class="echa-styled live container-fluid"> 
 <div id="content-wrapper"> 
 <a href="#main-content" id="skip-to-content"> 
Skip to Content</a> 
 <header id="banner" role="banner"> 


*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do as simple as:

```
$html = preg_replace('/>\s*</', ">\n<", $html);
```